# PhoneGap or JqueryMobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've built and app on PhoneGap (Cordova) and run into plenty of difficulties along the way. Thus I was thinking my next build would be with jQuery Mobile.

I was wondering if anyone had experience with both and had a recommendation or preference?

Comment: I use JqueryMobile over PhoneGap, the former for UI, the latter as a layer between javascript and native features. So... why choose?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JQM just helps you build a web page/application that is optimized for mobile devices, however it is still just a web page. On iOS you can pin a web application to the home-screen which opens up a separate browser instance when clicked/tapped as well as provide some meta tags that can make your web application appear more like a native app (for example you can hide the status bar at the top of the screen and provide a splash screen). On android however (at least on ICS, don't know about Jelly bean), while you can pin web application to your home-screen it just acts as a shortcut and opens it up as another tab in your browser. I'm not sure what options you have for web apps on windows phones.

Phonegap just builds a native app wrapper with a webview (a browser instance) for your web application and gives you access to the devices API.

Basically the two are not mutually exclusive, you can build your web application using JQM and still wrap it up in phonegap (you'll probably still run into whatever difficulties you ran into before), or you can skip the phonegap part, but your web application will still be just a web application, i.e a web page (that is more apparent on android then iOS).

Comment: Ah ok, so would I be correct in assuming I would create the basis of the app in phonegap, but add extra functionality and animations using JQM?

Comment: Yes, you might want to take a look at this page in the JQM documentation http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Titanium from http://appcelerator.com

Comment: why would you recommend this?

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that Jquerymobile does not support is the native device api. I've done development with both, but atleast with android, creating an interface for javascript function calls was easy. The Jquery mobile ui's work quite smoothly on many different android phones, even low end.

Currently I'm using just jquery mobile, the difference being here that its just for the ui, not an API for device functionality. Also, im doing the jquery mobile development through titanium, 
http://www.appcelerator.com/platform