# What is the difference between installing JQuery Mobile application on a device using Google Play Store and using PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile

What is the difference between installing JQuery Mobile application on a device using Google Play Store and using PhoneGap?

Also, is there other tools we can use to install Jquery application on devices besides PhoneGap?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't install an application using PhoneGap. Phonegap is a framework that lets you develop apps using html 5/javascript. After you develop your app you still have to publish it on Google Play if you want users to install it. Jquery Mobile is also a framework, designed to develop webpages optimized for mobile screens.

[There is a good post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239704/phonegap-or-jquerymobile) Explaining the differences between phonegap and jquery mobile.

There are several other mobile web frameworks such as [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/), [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/), [kendo ui](http://www.kendoui.com/), and I am sure you can find others if you run a quick search for it.

You need to read a little about them and understand the differences and advantages between them. [Googling "Phonegap vs Titanium"](http://bit.ly/16psxlP) for example will give you a good start point to understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap is just a cross-platform framework to develop mobile applications. You can use HTML, CSS, JS (incl. jQuery and jQuery Mobile) to develop in PhoneGap. In order to test applications, you can transfer them to your device using tools provided by PhoneGap and the Android SDK.

But in order to publish your application and make it available for others in the Google Play Store, you have to create a developer account ($25 at the time of writing this) and upload your application package (APK) there.

- [PhoneGap Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) (read "deploy to device")
- [Android Guide "Using hardware devices"](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)
- [Android Guide "Get started with publishing"](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html)

There are also other cross-platform frameworks available such as "Titanium". Keep in mind that jQuery Mobile is only a Javascript (jQuery) extension to help building user interfaces that resemble conventional app behavior and look. It is not a complete framework to build your application.